# Why using Number(num) != num instead of ~~num != num throws "JavaScript heap out of memory"?

Tags: javascript, heap-memory

I'm trying to validate input: if num is anything other than an integer or integer-formatted string, then throw a TypeError. When I'm trying to validate input like this, all working:

```
function prefill(n, v) {
  let testArr = [];
  let num  = n;
//input validation
    if(~~num != num || typeof num == 'boolean' || +num < 0) throw new 
TypeError(num + ' is invalid')

    else {
      for (let i = 0; i < +n; i++) {
        testArr.push(v);
      } 
      return testArr;    
 }
}
```

But when I try this way,

```
if(Number(num) != num || +num < 0)
```

I've got this error "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Comment: which browser or JS engine?

Comment: And what were the `n` and `v` parameters when you got that error?

Comment: I'm doing it in www.codewars.com.  I got an error with parameters( infinite, - infinite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

How many elements are going to be pushed into the array?
The bit-wise '~~' comparison parses it to a 32 bit result. A max of 2^31 items.

Number() is going to give you a floating point that can potentially run that for loop and push 'v' 1.7976931348623157e+308 (Number.MAX_VALUE) times. That is going to have you out of memory sooner or later.